# Python put add sentence as image in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, visualization, seaborn

I have a text:

```
"Hello world"
```

and a heat map as a 2d-array.

I want to draw the text as a graph in order to put the heatmap on top of it.

So, my question is how to convert the string "Hello world" to an image in order to plot it?

For example, I want to create this .png:

[image: out]

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/demo_text_path.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save an image with the text:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

img = Image.new('RGB', (200, 100))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text((20, 20), 'Hello World', fill=(255, 0, 0))
img.save("image.png")
```

and then you can plot against it.

EDIT:

to add a font-type:

```
d.text((20, 20), 'Hello World', fill=(255, 0, 0), font=ImageFont.truetype("arial"))
```

EDIT 2:

to change the font size:

```
font_size = 30
d.text((20, 20), 'Hello World', fill=(255, 0, 0), font=ImageFont.truetype("arial",fontsize))
```

Comment: Thanks great! is it possible to change the set a bounding box of the text? Meaning let's say I want "Hello world" to go from x=-30 to x=120

Comment: @okuoub Do you mean the positioning of the text? x=120 would make the text float to right in this case, `d.text((20, 120), 'Hello World', fill=(255, 0, 0))`

Comment: No I mean a bounding box - not only the starting positioning but also the ending (And the between-letter spaces and letters size will be determined accordingly? If no, is there another way to change the font size?

Comment: `d.text` - doesn't do any formating, it just prints string at the given location, If you want to change the background of the image you can pass an additional argument like: `img = Image.new('RGB', (200, 100), (255, 255, 255))`

Comment: @okuoub Added a way to change the font style.

Comment: Thanks! No way to dictate the size?